# How to express a lowercase followed by any case char using BNF?

Tags: intellij-idea, bnf, intellij-plugin, grammar-kit

I am trying to learn how IntelliJ Grammar Kit works for creating a BNF

How can I define an identifier that stars with 'v' and then have any case. e.g. 'vModule'.

Here is my attempt:

```
identifier ::= "v"id
```

But then, instead of 'vModule', it expects 'v Module'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the actual regular expression matching your identifier into the token definition. Something like:

```
identifier ::= "regexp:v\w+"
```

Comment: thanks. Is there any alternative way to combine tokens to make them a single token? e.g. when they are complex to be captured as a single regex.